# Curl request not working from same origin

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-302

Hi i have a website say `abc.com`  and there is a another site which is installed in the subfolder  `abc.com/site` .When i am making a curl request from the abc.com/site  to abc.com it is showing 302 .
below is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data['username'] = 'abc';
$data['password'] = 'abc';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "abc.com/site ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($a);
```

but when i am making the same request to the production site from the dev site it works well.  It seems like it is not working on the same origin. Please suggest how can i fix this

Comment: instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "abc.com/site ");` try with http or https what you have there like:- http://.....

Comment: yes i tried that already but no luck

Comment: I'm not sure, this may help you: turn true for  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` and check

Answer (score 0):

302 is a redirect and you have explicitly told curl to not follow redirects with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to false...